# How to connect to a heroku postgres databases using databases library in fastapi?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am trying to connect to the Heroku Postgres database using the `databases` python library in `fastapi`.

Following is my code

```
import databases
import sqlalchemy
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL,ssl = True)

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,  pool_pre_ping=True,)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(database.engine)

...
```

On running it shows the following error:

```
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

I want to use `databases` to use the async feature in `fastapi`. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Heroku platform so I don't know if they just simply use self signed certificates for database connectivity but if you're sure that you trust this cert you can create a new SSL context and disable verification:

```
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL, ssl=ctx)
...
```